# convert from cvs to bzr

Tags: cvs, bazaar

cvsps-import doesn't support pserver
bzr-fastimport doesn't support remote locations
tailor is too hard
bzrcvsserve isn't a conversion tool

SourceForge is remote, uses pserve and many python bookmark projects (what I'm looking for) are in CVS...

What now?

Answer (score 2):

If your CVS repository hosted on SourceForge then you can download entire repo via rsync and then use bzr-fastimport with cvs2svn (cvs2bzr) tool.

Answer (score 0):

You could import into a local temporary git repository and then import into Bazaar from there?  Tailor is really your tool of choice, but maybe the git tools will prove "easier" (can't imagine how, but there's a time and place for everything, i guess).

Comment: omg!!! Tailor??? There are svn and git integration for Bazaar Explorer, but no cvs integration, I wonder why...

Comment: Is it better to convert from cvs to svn to bzr or from cvs to git to bzr or using any of those ways no history loss and things like that?

Comment: Who knows?  I would think CVS->SVN is a simpler transition than CVS->Git, but then Git->Bazaar is probably simpler than SVN->Bazaar, so you're going to have to trust the toolchain somewhere.  CVS->SVN works very well.  I can't comment on any other section of the conversion, but it would seem to me that getting out of CVS is the largest challenge in this chain, so I would go CVS->SVN->Bzr